# Error "element is detached from the DOM" after vising a link in a loop

Tags: cypress

I am trying to do smoke testing by clicking links in a list. After first visit the test stops with following error.

```
CypressError: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

<a href="/link2">...</a>

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

> cy.wrap()
```

What do i do to hold on the element in the loop ?

```
it('Click each link in the list', () => {
  cy.get('li a').each(($el, index, $list) => {
     cy.wrap($el).click();
     cy.go(-1);
  })
})
```

The objective of the test is to check if all pages in the list come up without 404 errors. Following the html code

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/link3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you invoke cy.get(), you will save the references, and then you navigate away by clicking the link - hence the references to these elements are no longer valid.
You could make a list of ids for these elements:

```
const listOfIds = ['#first_id', '#second_id']
listOfIds.forEach(id => cy.get(id).click())
```

or if you want to generate your list dynamically, you could do that as well:

```
function getIds(){
            let ids = []
            return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
                cy.get('.your-selector')
                    .each($el =>
                        cy.wrap($el)
                            .invoke('attr', 'id')
                            .then(id => ids.push(id))
                    )
                    .then(() => resolve(ids))
            })
        }
```

After that calling `getIds().then(ids => ids.forEach(...))` is basically the same as above.

Comment: Thank you. Just the thinking I was looking for.